# dynamically load a user control in the aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following aspx page for eg: called choosemenu.aspx

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
     <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div>
         </div>
       <div id="renderhere" runat="server">render user control here </div>
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I have a list of ascx pages called

```
 english.ascx
 commerce.ascx
 maths.ascx
```

I have to dynamically load the ascx files in  my aspx page depending on the querystring in the aspx page.

I have the following contents in my aspx page in page_load event.

```
   var control = (English)Page.LoadControl("/ascx/english.ascx");
```

How will I  render the contents of the english.ascx page in the choosemenu.aspx that too in this   tag

Also I have to pass some value in the ascx file. This is the static stuff.

```
   <Menu:MNU ID="english" runat="server" HiLiter="<%#h %>"></Menu:MNU>
```

Comment: do these user controls need to postback values?

Comment: The user control has to pass some values

Comment: in that case, you must load and reload them on or before the OnInit phase in order for the postback values to be hydrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Loading a control from the server side**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/ascx/english.ascx")); //CHECK THE PATH 
}
```

**Loading a control from the server side and rendering it into a div**
If you want to render it in a specific `div` you might write:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/ascx/english.ascx");
    uc.MyParameter = 1;
    uc.Id = 2;
    uc.someMethodToInitialize();
    div1.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```

and in your `aspx` page:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">

</div>
```

**Loading a control from the server side initializing the control with parameters**

If your `control` has a `constructor` with `parameters`, you have to use:

public English_Control(int MyParameter, int Id)
{
    //code here..
}

In you `aspx.cs` file you can initialize with:

```
UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl(typeof(English_Control), new object[] {1, 2});
div1.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Comment: Need to change this answer to allow for postback values. See comments on OPs question

Answer (score 3):

In order for the control's postback values to be available, you must load and reload it no later than PreInit. Here is the code you need to do that.

```
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        string controlToLoad = String.Empty;
        //logic to determine which control to load
        UserControl userControl = (UserControl)LoadControl(controlToLoad);
        renderhere.Controls.Add(userControl);
        base.OnPreInit(e);
    }
```

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#general_page_lifecycle_stages):

> Pre-Init event used to "Create or re-create dynamic controls."